# debian xfce screen resolution reverts randomly and after suspend

Tags: debian, xfce, display-settings

I've come over to Debian from Ubuntu - great!

I'm using `xfce4` as the desktop environment.

One issue is my chosen screen resolution reverts to a default - both randomly while I'm on the PC (just happened now while typing this!), and it also reverts after the PC returns from suspend. I choose 1920x1080 in `Settings->Display`, but the system reverts to 3840x2160.

However, the system saves the 1920x1080 config when I reboot or stop/start.

I'm guessing there may be a setting in a file I can tweak?

Comment: "just happened now while typing this!" was it while you were doing activity (ie between two keystrokes), or could that be after some inactivity time and some power saving activating?

Comment: good question, can't remember, I guess it might have been about to do power saving exactly when I resumed typing

Comment: The windowing system actually completely crashed when I paused whilst writing the above reply! I had to push the pc’s power button till it went off, then restart the electricity to the pc, to be able to restart the pc, to get the graphical environment back. Hmm.

Comment: I also tried saving a profile under `Settings->Display->Advanced` as suggested here: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=15985 - no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not really an answer (?) ... I installed Cinnamon, it retains the resolution after suspend
`sudo apt install task-cinnamon-desktop

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).